# Running `ls` in git repository results in `git status --porcelain --ignore`

Tags: ls, git

When connected to our production server over `ssh`, sometimes when running `ls` inside a git repository and simultaneously looking at the output of `htop` I can see a process `git status --porcelain --ignore` appearing as a child of `ls`. I can spot this when the server's disk IO is saturated and the execution of `ls` takes long enough for one to see the short lived git command. Why is the aforementioned git command being run as a child of `ls`?

Answer (score 3):

Your `ls` command may in fact be an alias to someting more complicated; you can try by running instead `/bin/ls` or `\ls`, you should not see the same behavior. The `alias` command could show you if you have an aliased `ls` and to what.

Also your shell prompt could be configured to run such a command: it is "common" to put various git information (state of the directory, lastest commit ID, branch name, etc.) inside one's prompt and to do that `git status` must be run automatically after each command invocation.

Comment: in bash, `type ls` will show you where it's coming from - whether an executable, alias, or a shell function.